# What are the (ill) effects of drawing too many amps through a DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, amperage

I am running 256 WS2811b RGB LED "pixels" off a 5V 8A power supply. After about a week, I'm noticing the power supply runs quite hot and I'm worried I'm damaging it (or causing some other ill effects that I"m not aware of).

Since a lot of the time the LEDs are near full RGB max brightness, I'm using the full 60mA/"pixel" to calculate peak current draw, which is working out to ~15A.

I'm keeping this project disconnected until I get some responses here just in case!

Comment: You are exceeding the ratings of the PSU. If it doesn't current limit it will overheat with potential fire risk.

Comment: If you downvote, please indicate why in the comments. This gives me the opportunity to improve my question and benefits the community.

Comment: Well. there's 2 unrelated questions in one. Also questions on how to use devices are off topic. Drawing 15 A from an 8 A supply which gets hot, what are you thinking ????

Comment: Power supplies have current ratings for a reason. Don't exceed them. Your have three and only three options that are sensible: 1) Get a more powerful supply. 2) Find a way to lower the consumption so that it doesn't exceed the rating. 3) Scrap the project altogether.

Comment: Thanks @Bimpelrekkie for the comment. I have removed the unrelated question. "What was I thinking"? I was thinking: I'm a noob and didn't know better. Now I'm learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm keeping this project disconnected until I get some responses here just in case!

I'm afraid nobody (sensible) is going tell you that all is OK and that you should carry on.

A little background info.

- Power supplies are generally used to convert power from one voltage and current to another.
- The relationship between power (P), voltage (V) and current (I) is given by the simple equation \$ P = VI \$.
- If your supply was 100% efficient the \$ P_{IN} = P_{OUT} \$. For simplicity here we will assume that it is.
- You require 15 A at 5 V so \$ P_{OUT} = VI = 5 \times 15 = 75 \; W \$.
- In Canada your mains voltage is 120 V. The current you will draw from your mains will be \$ I = \frac {P}{V} = \frac {75}{120} = 0.625 \; A \$. Give that your power supply < 100% efficient the actual mains current will be more like 0.8 to 1 A.

Your power supply contains various components such as resistors, semiconductors and wires or PCB traces each of which has a maximum operating temperature. The temperature will rise on each until the power lost as heat = electrical power input to each component. This is thermal equilibrium.

The power dissipated in each component will also be given by \$ P = VI \$ but this time \$V\$ will be the voltage drop across that particular component. Now if you double the current drawn from your supply \$I\$ will double but so will the voltage drop across the component (typically). Power dissipated could now be four times what it was originally. The new thermal equilibrium will be at a much higher temperature. Once this exceeds the component's maximum it dies - often in smoke.

Fire is a very real hazard in budget power supplies as every corner has been cut to shave the last cent off the price.